# Javascript: Taking the contents of a page element and using it as a variable?

Tags: javascript, element, countdown

So I have two scripts on a page:

- The first one randomly chooses a number from an array and inserts it into an element called 'number'.
- The second one is a countdown script which counts down from two variables which are interpreted as minutes and seconds. It then plays a sound once the countdown has reached zero.

At the moment, the second script is all manually set-up, so the number of minutes and seconds are hard-coded into the script itself. I'd like the second script to take whatever number was inserted into the page by the first script, and use it as its variable.

Here's a better example of how I'd like it to work:

You load the page, and it tells you that you only have (X) minutes to spare (X = inserted by first script), and whatever (X) is, acts as the 'minutes' variable in the second script, which is now displaying a countdown from (X) minutes elsewhere on the page.

The first script's output is inserted into:

```
<span id="minutes"></span>
```

And here's the code for the second script (the one that needs changing):

```
var interval;
var minutes = 5;
var seconds = 0;
window.onload = function() {
    countdown('countdown');
}

    function play(file) {
var embed = document.createElement("embed");

embed.setAttribute('src', file);
embed.setAttribute('hidden', true);
embed.setAttribute('autostart', true);

document.body.appendChild(embed);
}

function countdown(element) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                el.innerHTML = "Time's up!";                    
                clearInterval(interval);
    play('alarm.mp3');
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I've tried changing

```
var minutes = 5;
var seconds = 0;
```

to

```
var minutes = document.getElementById(minutes);
var seconds = 0;
```

(the second script runs after the first one)

... but it doesn't seem to work, just starting at 'null' minutes.

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

```
var minutes = Number(document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML);
```

### Explanation:

You probably mean the string minutes: (add quotes)

```
var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
var seconds = 0;
```

But that returns the DOM object.  The innerHTML will return what is inside the `<span>` tag

```
var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML;
```

But then you need to realise that it is a string everywhere it is used, so that where you might have had implicit type conversions with `string + number` you will now have to do it explicitly, or change code to allow for implicit conversion, or handle it when you first instantiate minutes.

Thus we do the type conversion using `Number()`

Comment: They also need to use the contents of the span and not the DOM element itself, try accessing its `innerHTML` or something.

Comment: Man, just look at the length of the question and the length of the solution.. +1!

Comment: Hey, I've tried this but it just ignores the minutes element altogether now: http://jsfiddle.net/F3KL4/

Comment: @SnowBlind Sorry to dissapoint, but there were a lot of gotchas I had to add in there.

Comment: @DMoses Absolutely no problem, this looks better than my edit.

Comment: @user1548172 Sorry I went through a few revisions of the solution because I wanted it to look pretty.  It should be what you need now.

Comment: Saw your edited version: all working now, thanks! I'm kind of new to Javascript so I'm not sure what the implications of it being a string every time are?

Comment: @user1548172 given S1 = '1', S2 = '2', N3 = 3 the following hold true:  S1 + S2 => '12', N3 + S1 => 4, Number(S1) + S2 => 3.  Worth just googling implicit type conversion in javascript if you don't follow.